# Get json value separately

Tags: php, arrays, json, multidimensional-array

Trying to Separate data from this array here is the following code i am working on right now please help

```
$url=file_get_contents('https://corona-api.com/countries');

$data = json_decode($url);
```

here is the output in array which come after print_r the $data i tried some ways but did not understood the array sturcture

```
stdClass Object
(
    [data] => Array
        (
            [0] => stdClass Object
                (
                    [coordinates] => stdClass Object
                        (
                            [latitude] => 33
                            [longitude] => 65
                        )

                    [name] => Afghanistan
                    [code] => AF
                    [population] => 29121286
                    [updated_at] => 2020-03-28T06:54:16.562Z
                    [today] => stdClass Object
                        (
                            [deaths] => 0
                            [confirmed] => 0
                        )

                    [latest_data] => stdClass Object
                        (
                            [deaths] => 4
                            [confirmed] => 110
                            [recovered] => 2
                            [critical] => 0
                            [calculated] => stdClass Object
                                (
                                    [death_rate] => 
                                    [recovery_rate] => 
                                    [recovered_vs_death_ratio] => 
                                    [cases_per_million_population] => 3
                                )

                        )

                )

            [1] => stdClass Object
                (
                    [coordinates] => stdClass Object
                        (
                            [latitude] => 41
                            [longitude] => 20
                        )

                    [name] => Albania
                    [code] => AL
                    [population] => 2986952
                    [updated_at] => 2020-03-28T06:54:16.562Z
                    [today] => stdClass Object
                        (
                            [deaths] => 0
                            [confirmed] => 0
                        )

                    [latest_data] => stdClass Object
                        (
                            [deaths] => 8
                            [confirmed] => 186
                            [recovered] => 31
                            [critical] => 3
                            [calculated] => stdClass Object
                                (
                                    [death_rate] => 
                                    [recovery_rate] => 
                                    [recovered_vs_death_ratio] => 
                                    [cases_per_million_population] => 65
                                )

                        )

                )
```

i am trying to get country wise data but after getting this data in array i am having trouble to separate the data please help me

Comment: show us value of `$data`. As well as post the code which you used to iterate over `$data`

Comment: @AnantSingh---AlivetoDie i have edited my post please tell me a way to do it

Comment: If you have the data structure, you can make a first attempt at how to read it.  If you try something but aren't able to get the data you are after, then ask for further help.

Comment: @NigelRen i tried bro